# WebAPI Non-interactive authenticating to Azure AD using username & password

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a Rest service hosted on Azure with Azure AD Authentication enabled on it.  I am consuming this Web service in Microsoft Add in.

I do not want to prompt the Microsoft login page to user. Instead login in back ground using his user name and password and get access token and refresh token.

I have been using below code :

```
 private static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
 AuthenticationResult result = null;
 string user = "";
 string password = "";
 string resrouce = "web service URL";
 authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());

 UserCredential uc = new UserPasswordCredential(user, password);
 result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, uc).Result;
```

The exception for this code is “The request body must contain the following parameter: client_secret or client_assertion” . I did not find a way to pass client secret or client assertion with User credentials.

I have also tried below code.  In below code using Client ID and Client Secret key and getting back an access token that will expire in an hour and this code does not return refresh token. This access token is not specific to the user.

```
 string tenantName = "contoso.com";
 string authString = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantName;
 AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authString, false);
string clientId = "a3b4eef4-33f0-4e98-9d57-ad14549bf310";
string key = "Secret Key";
ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, key);
string resource = "Service URL ";
string token;
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCred).Result;
token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

is there any way to get the access token and refresh token from Azure AD without prompting user Microsoft login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems you register a web app/API in azure ad that uses username and password to authenticate . we can only use the resource owner flow from a native client. A confidential client, such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials.

You would need to invoke it as a public client (native client app), not as a confidential client (web app/API). Please refer to [this document](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) for more about how to use ADAL .NET to authenticate users via username/password .Especially the `Constraints & Limitations` section .

You can also use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) in your scenario , but with this flow, the application presents its client credentials to the OAuth2 token issuing endpoint, and in return gets an access token that represents the application itself without any user information.  There is **no need** for the application to get a refresh token. When the access token expires, it simply goes back to the OAuth2 token issuing endpoint to get a new one.

Comment: Yes, I have used the client credential flow. and able to get the access token. I hope I will work with multiple users at a same time